# Action upon suspected sock puppeting

Tags: support, sock-puppets

About an hour ago I received a series of upvotes. All on different, unrelated questions and answers, all within a few minutes window. This obviously raised a red flag.

Should I do anything with this or just wait for Community user to sort it out?

Comment: If the number of upvotes crosses a certain threshold the system will shortly automatically reverse such serial voting.